# Cannot find Eclipse libraries even when specified as dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing part of an Eclipse plug-in. Currently the IDE is saying that packages such as `org.eclipse.ui` can't be resolved.
I have correctly added `org.eclipse.ui` to the `plugin.xml` as dependencies required, as you can see in this picture:

[image: Picture showing the plugin.xml view in Eclipse, containing references to the packages mentioned above.]

As you can see the packages are listed but have the small red `x` symbol that indicates that something is wrong. If I try to select one of those names and try to go to declaration and such the IDE cannot find the package.

The IDE I'm using is an Eclipse Neon **RCP**, *freshly installed* on my Ubuntu system. AFAICT these packages should come with eclipse itself, if not
how can I install them?

Note I previously used an older Eclipse RCP version to write the code. I'm positive that I did not have to install any special package for development. However I had some other issues and I decided to switch to Neon.

Comment: What are the error messages in the Problems view? These plugins must be already installed because Eclipse itself would not work without them. What Target Platform are you using (Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform)?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I noticed that the Target Platform itself had the red `x`, removed it and restored defaults and it suddenly fixed this issue. Is the target platform stored in the workspace? Because as I said the IDE was freshly installed.

Comment: Yes it is stored in the workspace

Answer (score 1):

Check the Target Platform is valid (in the 'Preferences' in 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform).

The target platform definitions are part of the workspace and might become invalid when you upgrade.

It is generally a good idea to use a separate target platform rather than the default 'Running Platform' as it gives you more control over which plug-ins are available and is less likely to become invalid during upgrades.